# Container-Agnostic Websocket throws NPE with Embedded Jetty

Tags: servlets, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty, java-websocket

I'm writing a container-agnostic Websocket server.  My development environment uses IntelliJ IDEA with an embedded Jetty version `9.3.11.v20160721` (embed code below).

My code, however, uses the Tomcat Websocket libraries, `tomcat-websocket-api` and `tomcat-websocket`, version `8.5.4`.

I want to register the Websocket `EndPoint` with a `ServletContextListener`.  Following some examples from the [Tyrus project](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.13/index/deployment.html), as well as some answers on SO and in the Jetty mailing list by Joakim Erdfelt (@joakim-erdfelt), I wrote the following implementation and added it via a `listener` in `web.xml`.

The code enters the `contextInitialized()` method so that part seems to work properly, but unfortunately the ServletContext does not contain the attribute `javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer` and therefore it returns null.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    final ServerContainer serverContainer = (ServerContainer) servletContextEvent
            .getServletContext()
            .getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer");

    // *** serverContainer is null ***

    try {
        serverContainer.addEndpoint(ChatAnnotation.class);
    } 
    catch (DeploymentException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

The only available attributes are `javax.servlet.context.tempdir`, `org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory`, `org.eclipse.jetty.tlds`, `org.eclipse.jetty.resources`, `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Executor`, `org.eclipse.jetty.webFragments`

What am I doing wrong?  Is this strictly an embedding-issue?  Will it run properly in standard Jetty (i.e., not embedded)?

The embed code is below:

```
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/");
webapp.setResourceBase(webroot);   
webapp.setDescriptor(webroot + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");

Server server = new Server();

ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setPort(8080);             

server.setConnectors(new ServerConnector[] { connector });
server.setHandler(webapp);      
server.start();
server.join();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSR ServerContainer isn't initialized automatically in embedded-jetty.

Use the `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer` ...

```java
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/");
webapp.setResourceBase(webroot);   
webapp.setDescriptor(webroot + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");

Server server = new Server();

ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setPort(8080);             

server.setConnectors(new ServerConnector[] { connector });
server.setHandler(webapp);

// Add this line
WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(webapp);

server.start();
server.join();
```

Note: The `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer` is a `javax.servlet.ServerContainerInitializer` and you could set up your `embedded-jetty` to execute that `ServerContainerInitializer` automatically.

If you heavily rely on bytecode scanning of annotations, or have a `javax.websocket.server.ServerApplicationConfig` implementation, then you'll want to have the `ServerContainerInitializer` execute automatically.

> Note: the `javax.servlet.ServerContainerInitializer` is only valid for a `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext`.
>
> If you use the `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler` (the more common form in embedded-jetty) then you cannot use a `javax.servlet.ServerContainerInitializer`.

To set that up, do this:

```java
private void enableAnnotationScanning(Server server)
{
    Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
    classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
    classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
}

// ... later on ...

Server server = new Server();
enableAnnotationScanning(server);
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer.  So to clarify, this is strictly an embed issue and should not happen when deployed to standard Servlet containers, is that correct?

Comment: Adding that line throws another NPE early on: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50113', transport: 'socket'
 at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:100)`

Comment: I updated your answer.  Had to move the line down after `server.setHandler(webapp)` and that fixed both NPEs.  Thanks!

Comment: As long as you have the `--module=websocket` enabled in your `jetty-distribution` it will work without that extra line required.

Comment: I actually try to avoid scanning due to the long delays that they add to startup times.  The embedded-Jetty is used mostly for development purposes, so adding that line is not an issue.  I was debating whether to use the `Jetty-Websocket` vs the `Tomcat-Websocket` for this project, and the Tomcat's dependencies seem a bit more "organized" (I could be wrong), so at least for the time being I chose Tomcat.  I might switch to Jetty since you guys provide great support here.