# How to get Jetty to auto-discover Websocket endpoints?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I'm using an embedded Jetty server to, among other things, serve a Websocket endpoint. I'm loading it like this:

```
WebAppContext webAppContext = ...
// server.setHandler call in between here somewhere
ServerContainer container = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(webAppContext);
container.addEndpoint(MyEndpoint.class);
```

I have to explicitly specify my endpoint class(es) here. Can I instead get Jetty to discover them, using the `@ServerEndpoint` annotation on those classes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42565423/775715

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39440322/775715